# Java - Strange concurrent problems about ReentrantLock

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I have 2 test cases, while the first one is failed and the second one can successed.
The only difference code is method `incr` of class `Incr`.
Why?

```
public class ReentrantSpinLockTest {
    private final Incr incr = new Incr();

    @Test
    public void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        int n = 50;
        int inner_loop = 100_000;
        CountDownLatch boot = new CountDownLatch(n);
        CountDownLatch complete = new CountDownLatch(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    boot.await();
                    for (int k = 0; k < inner_loop; ++k) {
                        incr.incr();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } finally {
                    complete.countDown();
                }
            }).start();
            boot.countDown();
        }
        complete.await();
        int expect = n * inner_loop;
        int actual = incr.getI();
        assert expect == actual : String.format("expect %d actual %d", expect, actual);
    }

}
```

The successful Incr:

```
public class Incr {
        private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        private volatile int i;

        // only this diff
        public void incr() {
            lock.lock();
            lock.lock();
            i++;
            lock.unlock();
            lock.unlock();
        }

        public int getI() {
            return i;
        }
    }
```

The failed Incr:

```
    public class Incr {
        private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        private volatile int i;

        public void incr() {
            int k = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 5);
            for (int t = 0; t < k; ++t) {
                lock.lock();
            }
            i++;
            for (int t = 0; t < k; ++t) {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public int getI() {
            return i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are aware that `k` can also be zero in second `incr` code? In such case no locking takes place; try adding 1 to `k`... It is a bit strange having such random behavior in testing (unit tests?)

Comment: Yes, I implement my own lock, but failed in this test. So I replace it with jdk lock and try to figure out the reason. Thank you.

Comment: ??? the problem is that the random number `k` can be zero (any number from 0 to 4, inclusive) - the loop will not iterate if `k = 0` - so no locking takes place if `k = 0` || add `1` to `k` and it will be at least one and locking will occur (at least once)

Comment: Generally, you shouldn’t use something like `Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 5)` but the dedicated method, `new Random().nextInt(5)`. But don’t create a new `Random` for every number, store it in a constant, then incorporate the fix, i.e. use `RANDOM.nextInt(4) + 1` to get a number from one to four. Or use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5)`.